# Docker CMD evaluation with ENTRYPOINT

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile, consul, registrator

I have a Dockerfile that falls into the `exec_entry p1_entry /bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd` category in the matrix found in [*Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  The behavior is not what I'm expecting.  I was expecting `/bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd` to evaluate first then get passed into `exec_entry p1_entry`.  What I am observing is that `/bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd` literally gets passed into `exec_entry p1_entry` which I think is funny.

To provide more context, I am specifically deriving a new Dockerfile from an [existing Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/gliderlabs/registrator/~/dockerfile/) where the parent has:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/registrator"]
```

I want to pass in specific command-line parameters from my Dockerfile:

```
FROM gliderlabs/registrator:v7
CMD echo "-ip=$EXTERNAL_IP consul://$CONSUL_HOST"
```

When I run my Docker image in a container:

```
$ docker run --rm --name=test-registrator --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock -e "EXTERNAL_IP=<some-ip>" -e "CONSUL_HOST=<some-consul-hostname>:8500" my/registrator
```

I get the following error:

```
2016/12/28 19:20:46 Starting registrator v7 ...
Extra unparsed arguments:
  -c echo "-ip=$EXTERNAL_IP consul://$CONSUL_HOST"
Options should come before the registry URI argument.

Usage of /bin/registrator:
  /bin/registrator [options] <registry URI>

-cleanup=false: Remove dangling services
-deregister="always": Deregister exited services "always" or "on-success"
-internal=false: Use internal ports instead of published ones
-ip="": IP for ports mapped to the host
-resync=0: Frequency with which services are resynchronized
-retry-attempts=0: Max retry attempts to establish a connection with the backend. Use -1 for infinite retries
-retry-interval=2000: Interval (in millisecond) between retry-attempts.
-tags="": Append tags for all registered services
-ttl=0: TTL for services (default is no expiry)
-ttl-refresh=0: Frequency with which service TTLs are refreshed
```

This means that `-c echo "-ip=$EXTERNAL_IP consul://$CONSUL_HOST"` is literally getting passed into `/bin/registrator` as the parameter.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of the use case where `/bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd` does not get evaulated first before getting passed into the `ENTRYPOINT`?  If the latter is true, then can you also explain the usefulness of this use case?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is exactly how it is supposed to work.

The value of CMD is just passed as a parameter to the ENTRYPOINT.

Main difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT is that CMD just provides default command argument to the ENTRYPOINT program and it's usually overridden by the arguments to *run* command.  On the other hand you have to redefine ENTRYPOINT explicitly with *--entrypoint* option if you want different command to be executed.

Also, notice there is a difference how things are executed depending on the way ENTRYPOINT and CMD are defined in the Dockerfile.  When they are defined as an array in the form of **['arg1', 'arg2']** this array is passed as is to the ENTRYPOINT command, with the first element of ENTRYPOINT being the program being executed.  In the other case when they are defined as a simple string like **arg1 arg2** this string is first passed is prepended by "/bin/sh -c" note that Docker does not execute /bin/sh and returns the result of evaluation back,  that string itself is passed to the ENTRYPOINT program.

So in your case you have to use array method of passing the arguments:

```
CMD  [-ip, $EXTERNAL_IP,  consul://$CONSUL_HOST]
```

Comment: Then I don't understand what is the point for this use case `exec_entry p1_entry /bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd`.  This would require the `exec_entry` application to handle the command which I think is strange.

Comment: Ahh,  missed that part.  It is actually degenerate case when CMD is defined in string form,  but your ENTRYPOINT is not a shell.   I don't think that it has any use.  The only use this syntax makes sense is when your ENTRYPOINT is a shell (bash, sh, csh) and you have command line like this "ls *.c"  this way the globs will work.  Otherwise ls will just get '*.c' as an argument and will look for a file named '*.c' not the set of files that end with '.c'

Comment: Thanks for your input!  I want to point out that (although it'd be nice) `CMD  [-ip, $EXTERNAL_IP,  consul://$CONSUL_HOST]` does not work because the environment variables don't resolve.  See [this article](http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/) under *Shell form* then *Exec form*.

Comment: Yes you right.  It's shell's Job to resolve globs and environment variables.  In your case I'd just redefine ENTRYPOINT in your own image to point to /bin/sh and  add a small shell script with /bin/registrator -ip=$EXTERNAL_IP consul://$CONSUL_HOST  this way you'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you struggling to understand the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile? Check out this article, 'Understanding the Difference Between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile:A Comprehensive Guide,' at https://code-craft.fr/understanding-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-dockerfile-a-comprehensive-guide/. It provides a comprehensive guide on the differences and best practices for effective use. This may help you gain a better understanding of these crucial components in Dockerfile.